# VisorFreeMind Flash Browser (FLA file)

Tags: flash

On http://sourceforge.net/projects/freemind you can download the source files for the VisorFreeMind flash browser but these are only the *.as files and no other files like images.

Does somebody have the compiled *.fla file for the freemind browser? Or knows how to get a *.fla from those *.as file (with mtasc??)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably have to make your own fla for it and add the main class for the FreeMind browser as the document class.

You could always get the [flex sdk](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+3) and use that to compile the .as into a .swf.  If you don't want to use the sdk directly, it ties nicely into [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/).